# Solr highlighting with unexpected prefix and suffix

Tags: solr, highlighting

I need to customize Solr highlighting prefix and suffix like this:

```
<span class="highlight">text</span>
```

instead of the default

```
<em>text</em>
```

That's why I'm using this configuration within the `solrconfig.xml` for the `HighlightComponent`:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
        <fragmentsBuilder name="simple" default="true" class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragmentsBuilder">
            <lst name="defaults">
                <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[<span class="highlight">]]></str>
                <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</span>]]></str>
            </lst>
        </fragmentsBuilder>
    </highlighting>
</searchComponent>
```

The following are the default parameters for my standard request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="hl">true</str>
        <str name="hl.fl">body,title</str>
        <str name="hl.useFastVectorHighlighter">true</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

When I search for the `text` word I do get the text word highlighted, but not always using the prefix and suffix I configured:

```
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="document_1">
        <arr name="body">
            <str>my <em>text</em> highlighted</str>
        </arr>
        <arr name="title">
            <str>my <span class="highlight">text</span> highlighted</str>
        </arr>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are seeing this behavior behavior because you only have the prefix and suffix defined for the SimpleFragmentsBuilder and the other highlights are coming from another fragment builder.

I am using a custom prefix and suffix for my highlighting and I set this value in the `formatter` section of the `highlighting` section of the solrconfig.xml and have not had any issues as it will apply to all fragment builders.

So maybe try the following:

```
 <highlighting>
   <fragmentsBuilder name="simple" default="true"
          class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragmentsBuilder"/>
   <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
   <formatter name="html" class="org.apache.solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter"
        default="true">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<span class="highlight">]]></str>
       <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</span>]]></str>
     </lst>
  </formatter>
 </highlighting>
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out why! I'm using [fastVectorHighlighter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.useFastVectorHighlighter) to make highlighting faster.
At the beginning I was highlighting only the `title` field and everything worked fine. 
When I added the `body` field to highlighting I forgot to enable [`termVectors=true`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options). 
Now that my `body` field looks like this

```
<field name="body" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
```

after a full reindex highlighting is working perfectly:

```
<lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="document_1">
        <arr name="body">
            <str>my <span class="highlight">text</span> highlighted</str>
        </arr>
        <arr name="title">
            <str>my <span class="highlight">text</span> highlighted</str>
        </arr>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Previously the body field highlighting did work, but without `fastVectorHighlighter` since the field didn't have the `termVectors=true` parameter. That's why I got `body` highlighted with default prefix and suffix. Since `fastVectorHighlighter` is a completely different highlighting method, the configuration is different as well.

To avoid this kind of mistakes, as long the users can choose what fields to highlight with the `hl.fl parameter`, I'd recommend to include also the configuration for the standard highlighting (formatter element, class `solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter`) like this:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
        <formatter name="html" default="true" class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
            <lst name="defaults">
                <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<span class="highlight">]]></str>
                <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</span>]]></str>
            </lst>
        </formatter>
        <fragmentsBuilder name="simple" default="true" class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragmentsBuilder">
            <lst name="defaults">
                <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[<span class="highlight">]]></str>
                <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</span>]]></str>
            </lst>
        </fragmentsBuilder>
    </highlighting>
</searchComponent>
```

This way highlighting will work with the same prefix and suffix even for fields with `termVectors` disabled.